# Is there a way to launch vscode from a bash shell so that a specific launch profile is active in debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've found that debugging some apps in vscode is tedious because the applications I work on have hundreds of command line parameters at times.  I have created a script that generates a launch profile for an app, given a command line, and adds it to launch.json.  It's relatively straightforward at that point to open the vscode GUI, start debug mode, and select the launch profile I've just added.  But it does take time (sometimes more than you'd think-- if there are many such profiles).  So I'd like to make the process even more automated--Ideally, I'd like to have the script that generates the launch profile to just go ahead and launch code, already in debug mode with that new profile activated, so that I can start execution with a single click.  Might not seem like this would save me much time, but I do this often, and it adds up quickly.

So far, though, I've not found a way to accomplish this.  Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you keep `launch.json` simple (1 config) and let the script replace the config,

Comment: I only (ever) have 4 configs, and I need them all.  When I said "it adds up quickly", I ,didn't mean the number of configs-- I meant the time spent clicking on Run, then "Start Debugging", then moving the mouse down to the right line in the list box, and clicking the config.  On a high-latency remote connection, that eats up time.  And it eats up a TON more when I accidentally click on the wrong config, and don't notice until the debug run finishes without hitting my breakpoint, because the wrong input was used.  That's more common than I'd like to admit, so I want to automate it away.

Comment: if you only have 4 max configs you can create keybindings to these 4 with [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config). Let the script generate the same names each time